# Multiple href ids

Tags: jquery

I'm using two jquery plugins:

scrollto and fading-tabs

both of them activate the function via the href attribute (href="#some-id")

How can i activate two ids in href on the same time? like:

```
href="#some-id1,#some-id2"
```

Comment: Could you activate one first and the other right after? (using `window.setTimeout`)

Comment: How can you scroll to two different IDs at the same time?

Comment: what you want to do is not clear, it may help if you paste your code.

Comment: one href is activating the scroll to a id, the other one decides which id tab will be used. see examples when clicking on a portfolio picture: http://teddyreklam.se/

I don't like the anchor script we use in this version so want to change to scrollto plugin but it uses the same href technique as fading tabs, so this is where my problem starts.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach to the click event handler yourself and invoke the specific methods you want instead of letting each plugin do it:

```
$('#myLink').unbind().click(function()
{
     var href = this.href;

     // Invoke other methods as you want here

     $(this).scrollto(/* Something with href.split(',')[0] */);
     $(this).fadingTabs(/* Something with href.split(',')[1] */);
});
```

Comment: ok, this looks promising, how will i implement the href, like this?:

$('#myLink').unbind().click(function()
{
     var href = this.href;

     $(this).scrollto(href.split('#some-id1')[0]);
     $(this).fadingTabs(href.split('#some-id2')[1]);
});

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. May be you can have 2 elements close to each other and set the `href` to these elements and then call the plugin on both of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to switch these to classes such as:

```
class="some-id1 some-id2"
```

Then do something like the following with your jQuery:

```
$(".some-id1").scroll....

$(".some-id2").fade....
```

Comment: i know about this technique but i don't know how to change the two jquery plugins to use class/id instead of href

Comment: Please post some sample code of the jquery plugins so that we can take a look

Comment: The two plugins can be found on: http://teddyreklam.se/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js
http://teddyreklam.se/js/fading-tabs.js

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a solution for solving the two hrefs. But for anybody who have tried to do the same thing:

have a tab switch and make the link scroll to the tab-container.

I solved the problem by building my own tab script with jquery and activating the tab by javacript through click function and then use .scrollTo as normal